# Blender keeps deleting linked libraries

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

I am working on a very big scene, therefore I have broken it down into smaller scenes, which then get all linked into one main file.

It works for a while. I can save, edit, re-open and no problem.

Then, all of a sudden, without me having done anything out of the ordinary to the file, next time I open it, all the linked libraries are missing.

The objects of these links still show, but the linked libraries are nowhere to be found. That means I cannot use the Edit Linked Library add-on, nor do the objects update in this main file once I save them.

Any ideas on why this happens and how to avoid it?

Thank you.

Comment: It happens to me as well with linked Character rigs.
I notice the path in which it looks for the missing files is actually a bad path that does not exist.
Do you happen to save into a different folder than the one where you originally created the first version of your file ?
Also are your save As settings set to [X] Remap Relative ? Mine are and without changing that It breaks all of a sudden, usually when I save to a new location which I thought was the whole point of remap relative.
So maybe there is a bug with the remap relative function ?